# Library symbols and user symbols in ELF

Tags: elf, symbol-table

My questions is related to symbols in an ELF. As we know an ELF's Symbol table holds information needed to locate and relocate a program’s symbolic definitions and references.

My question is that can we differentiate b/w a library symbol and user defined symbol (if both are global)? consider the scenario in which no source code is available and you have only ELF.

Comment: What do you mean by "library symbol" and "user defined symbols"?

Comment: from "library symbol" I mean library variables. same as user symbol means user defined variables in a program

Comment: But what makes them different? Consider implementing a library. Are those symbols user-defined or library?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, what do you need it for? Maybe stating that will make it clearer what exact difference you need to capture.

Comment: from library I mean glibc variables and functions. I have a linux ELF. I have made a run time tool which picks the functions from ELF and find the shared global variables with other functions on the fly. but I want this for user defined functions only( functions in the program) I don't want to include glibc functions (e.g., printf). is there any way to detect from symbol table?

Answer (score 0):

A static library is just an archive of unlinked object files (`.o`) (with index to speed up linker searching for symbols in it). When you link against such library, the linker takes each unresolved symbol and tries to find it there. If it finds it, it extracts corresponding object and adds it to the collection to link. So no, **you can't tell whether symbol comes from static library**.

If you have another instance of the library that is sufficiently close to what the executable was linked against, you could look which symbols it defines and than assume that all those symbols, plus any symbols those depend on, come from the library.

It is of course possible to tell symbols defined in shared library, because that remains different file.

But there is another point: It is most likely **illegal** to provide a Linux binary without sources statically linked against libc. That is, it is definitely illegal if that libc is the GNU Libc, because that is distributed under the terms of LGPL and LGPL requires providing (on request) sources of all derived code excepting code that is linked to it *dynamically*. If it uses different libc like [sourceware newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) or bionic libc (Android) (I can't find any other). I am not however sure how well such code would work in a GNU libc-based system.